# Multithreaded socket Program - Handling Critical section

Tags: python, python-multithreading, condition-variable, critical-section

I am creating a multi-threaded program, in which I want only 1 thread at a time to go in the critical section where is creates a socket and send some data and all the other to wait for that variable to clear.

1. I tried threading.Events but later realized that on set() it will notify all the threads waiting. While I only wanted to notify one.
2. Tried locks(acquire and release). It suited my scenario well but I got to know that lock contention for a long time is expensive. After acquiring the lock my thread was performing many functions and hence resulted in holding the lock for long.
3. Now I tried threading.conditions. Just wanted to know if acquiring and holding the condition for a long time, is it not a good practice as it also uses locks.
   Can anyone suggest a better approach to my problem statement.

Comment: Number two just sounds like you're making the scope of the critical section too large

Comment: If data creation takes too long maybe you should create it before entering the critical section

Comment: acc to https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/socket-programming-multi-threading-python/ this article, you can use acquire & release method.

Comment: @flakes Yes the critical section is too large but I cant build later because of some other constraints.

Comment: You cant magically make your code go any faster. You have a critical section that takes n seconds, and you the number of requests per second is greater than 1/n, therefore you will accrue backlog. No amount of locking can solve this issue. You need to reduce the time it takes to complete the critical section by reducing its scope, improving its performance, or running the code on faster hardware

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use an additional thread dedicated to sending. Use a [Queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html) where the other threads put their Send-Data. The socket-thread gets items from the queue in a loop and sends them one after the other.

As long as the queue is empty, `.get` blocks and the send-thread sleeps.

The "producer" threads have no waiting time at all, they just put their data in the queue and continue.

There is no concern about possible deadlock conditions.

To stop the send-thread, put some special item (e.g. None) in the queue.

To enable returning of values, put a tuple `(send_data, return_queue)` in the send-queue. when a result is ready, return it by putting it in the `return_queue`.

Comment: Yeah thanks.But its tool late for us to change the design. Can you please suggest the best option available from above or any other approach which will suit the existing design requirements and constraints.

Comment: You have two options. Have each producer thread send its data itself, protecting the socket with a lock, which is your option #2. Or, Queue the data to send and have an extra thread send it at its own pace. Which is what I suggested. Your option #2 causes lock contention as you mentioned, which is why it is considered bad design. So, either change the design or live with it.